# Submit Data to server from different fields not in same form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

In jquery, when you want to submit a form

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
    });
});
```

My problem is: I have a bunch of fields (that not in same form, or not in any form at all). And when I press send button, jquery will get values of all those fields and send to server (as sending a form).

I don't know how to this in jquery. Please tell me

thanks :)

Comment: $("form") will get all forms on the page, assign an id to a form for which u want to do the submit: $("#myform").submit...

Comment: because i must use developed on html template file. because css is poor design, if I put all fields into form element, style will be changed. that why those fields aren't in form field, and I need to collected all those fields by hand and submit to server. thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to send all the values in all the forms you have in the page and also some values that are not in any form and send all of them in a new form right?

```
  var theForm = $('<form></form>');

  $('form').find('input, textarea, select').each(function() {
        theForm.append('<input type="hidden" value='+ $(this).val() +' id='+$(this).attr('id') +' name ='+$(this).attr('id') +'>')
  });

  $('#input1, .moreinputs').each(function() {
         theForm.append('<input type="hidden" value='+ $(this).val() +' id='+$(this).attr('id') +' name ='+$(this).attr('id') +'>')
  });

  theForm.submit();
```

This way you can create a new form with all the values you need.

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML code does not requires input fields to be placed into a form tag. Just make sure your jQuery sector can identify them with id or classes so that you can extract the value in the field and sending it to the server for processing.

```
<!--<form action='...'>-->
<input id='myInputA' type='text'>  
<input id='myInputA' type='text'>
<!--</form>-->
<div id='myFakeFormButton' class='makeItLookLikeAFromButton'>Send</div>
```

Your script performing the ajax on specific input fields

```
//the script that can ignore any form values
$('#myFakeFormButton').on("click", function(){
    //get only the items you want to send.
    var input_A_Value = $('#myInputA').val();
    var input_B_Value = $('#myInputB').val();

    var myParamToSend = {
      paramA:input_A_Value,
      paramB:input_B_Value
    };

    $.ajax({
     url:'myFormProcessingPage.php',
     type:'POST',
     data: myParamToSend,
     success:function(result){
         console.log('processing form returned ', result);
     },
     error:function(error){
         console.error(error);
     }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:i.e:

```
var form1= $fomr1.serializeArray();//get all field form
form1.push({name:'test',value:'test2'}); //add other field
var ser=$.param( ui ); //serialize
```

and send by ajax i.e: $.post('url',ser,function(){})

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you are submitting all the forms in the page with `$("form").submit(...)`. You should select the form you want like `$("#form_id")`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form_id").submit(function(){
        alert("Submitted");
    });
});
```

Comment: because i must use developed on html template file. because css is poor design, if I put all fields into form element, style will be changed. that why those fields aren't in form field, and I need to collected all those fields by hand and submit to server. thanks :)